# Converting Mars Global DTM to Spherical Mesh

Tags: dem, convert, mars, unity3d

I am working on a video game that is attempting to provide a semi-realistic model of Mars. My starting point has been to find and use reliable geographic information to create the "model" of Mars.

I have found this [global 465m Digital Terrain Model](https://astrogeology.usgs.gov/search/map/Mars/GlobalSurveyor/MOLA/Mars_MGS_MOLA_DEM_mosaic_global_463m) of mars. It is provided in a CUB file which I believe just represents an elevation as a height value in a large 2D image.

I was hoping someone here knows of either a formula or methodology I could follow in order to convert from a raster "heightmap" into a spherical mesh. I know how to mesh a point cloud so even if I could get help in going from a raster heightmap to a point cloud I can take it from there.